# In terms of poetry, what is the Thomas code?

Tags: meaning, nouns, american-english, poetry

I was reading a book review of Wittgenstein's Mistress on goodreads, and I came across the sentence, "Without such accessible lecture notes, I may not have ever cracked the Thomas code and may never have become such an avid reader of poetry."

I am fairly sure that this has to do with poetry, but no amount of researching brought me to any concrete conclusions; a rabbit hole, you might say.

Comment: What's the broader context? Is it about education admin?

Comment: @Lawrence She was talking about how she really got started reading poetry and what led her to get interested in it.

Comment: Two possibilities that I can see.  One is that there is a reference book by a guy named Thomas (I see two or three candidates), but the book is inscrutable without the referenced lecture notes.  The second, a bit far out, is that this is somehow a reference to the "poem code" that is used for encryption.

Comment: @WhiteFang [This](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=coo.31924013369024;view=1up;seq=14) Thomas Code about education legislation or similar is rather lengthy, and I can imagine someone not 'cracking' (starting, or perhaps fully understanding) it without help, but that's just a wild guess, and one that I'm not fully satisfied with.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from the review on goodreads:

"Another side effect of purchasing used editions is chance that the former owner was, like myself, the type to underline and take various notes. This has been beneficial at times, such as a dirty softcover of Dylan Thomas’ Selected Poems I purchased from the Dawn Treader in Ann Arbor, MI (my personal favorite bookstore) when I was 19 and just beginning to immerse myself in the world of poetry. Despite seeing a slew of margin notes, my shallow pockets persuaded me to buy it anyways after seeing a $4 price sticker. Later at home while diving into Mr. Thomas’ work, I discovered the notes were incredibly insightful and detailed and further investigation led me to realize that it had once been used by a UofM professor for use in lecture. Without such accessible lecture notes, I may not have ever cracked the Thomas code and may never have become such an avid reader of poetry."

The "accessible lecture notes" are margin notes written in the edition of Dylan Thomas's poems by the former owner, a professor of literature for a lecture. "Cracking the Thomas code" means understanding the meaning of obscure references and images used by Thomas in his poetry.

Comment: An example of why  a user should always include the link to his source, so answerers don't have to do the work for him.